# Did Stein really ridicule Fischer for grabbing the poisoned pawn in the Najdorf Sicilian?

Tags: fischer, najdorf

I remember reading somewhere that Leonid Stein (one of the top players at that time) has ridiculed Bobby Fischer for grabbing the poisoned pawn in the Najdorf Sicilian during the Spassky-Fischer match in 1972. I wonder if that is really true. Perhaps it was a journalist's way of attracting readers' attention. Can anyone point me to a source of the citation?

Answer (score 3):

Although it is hard to prove a negative, I don't believe that Stein ridiculed Fischer for taking the poisoned pawn. My evidence is:

1. An analysis on [Chess.com](https://www.chess.com/blog/NimzoRoy/spassky---fischer-1972-wch-game-11-b97) of game 11 claims to source commentary of Stein's and others from *Fischer-Spassky 1972 From a Soviet Point of View*. Although I cannot find the original source, the commentary quoted on Chess.com is fair and balanced. In fact, 8...Qxb2 doesn't even receive a dubious mark
2. Googling [leonid stein ridicule](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=leonid%20stein%20ridicule) picks up no relevant articles on the first page
3. According to the *Chessmaster* database, Stein's co-comentators Bronstein and Korchnoi had grabbed the poisoned pawn before. I don't think that Stein would have been critical of a move that other top players had played before in a well analysed opening